# (Hash)-Map as RequestParam in a spring-boot application

Tags: spring-boot, http-request-parameters

- I want to specify filters for a CRUD `GET` REST controller for a list of items.
- The items I do return have a name `name: String`, a boolean property `isFoo: boolean` and `labels: Map<String, String>`.
- My list controller uses `q` for the `name`-filter and `isFoo` for the boolean property.
- Now I want to filter on `labels` as well.
- Additionally I use `org.springframework.data.domain.Page` to return sub-sets.
- I declared it naively like this and tested by adding `labels=%7Ba%3Db%2C+c%3Dd%7D`

```
@GetMapping("")
MyReturnType list(
  @RequestParam(defaultValue = 0) final int page,
  @RequestParam(defaultValue = 10) final int size,
  @RequestParam(defaultValue = true) final boolean isFoo,
  @RequestParam(required = false) final String q,
  @RequestParam(required = false, name = "labels") final Map<String, String> labels) {
...
}
```

- However I get a HTTP 500
- How may I specify this?

Comment: As far as I know, If @RequestParam specifies map as the parameter, otherwise the type conversion will fail. You should try replacing your map with a pojo